# I have three node dse graph cluster. Two node graph enabled one is search enabled. The problem is when i run api request goes on it does not response

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, dse-graph-frames

I have three node dse Cassandra cluster. One node is search enabled, Two node is graph enabled. When I run APIs(which is coded in scala play framework), POST or GET request keeps going and going it does gives a response. There is no any information in logs of Cassandra it is working normally.

Earlier i used to use single node cluster where is graph enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have same workload on all nodes of the same data center, so you need to enable both graph and search on all nodes.